# Hide a specific category title in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, hide, title

I have 5 categories in my wordpress, I was wondering how to hide just the title of one of the categories? I've tried some css but haven't been able to get it to work.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some `html`?

Comment: Here's a demo of the theme I'm using, https://modernthemes.net/wordpress-demo/resi/, you can change so the title shows up on hover on the images, I wish to just be able to show the hover title on a specific category, and not all o fthem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you could add custom classes to `.gallery-image`, then you could choose only those with this class and hide titles - https://jsfiddle.net/t41uzku4/. Unfortunately I can't say for WordPress if this is possible, because I didn't work with this CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for that https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/
I wonder that you want just to hide and display whatever time you want.